# Change input submit form control to button form control in Drupal 9 Forms API

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8, drupal-forms, drupal-9

I want to replace input submit form control by a button form control into Drupal 9 Forms API. It seems not to be standard because the type of the submit button seems to be hard coded into the Forms API. I can admit that there is some ways to customize the button by using configuration options but it is not enough for styling control correctly. My case is the following :

When I am styling forms, I need frequently to add some icons into buttons but this is not possible to use pseudo selectors `::before` or `::after` on submit input buttons.
The workaround I have found consists to add a div wrapper around my button but it is no really easy to fix elements placement issues in responsive.
This is because of this css styling limits that I want replace all input submit buttons by `<button>` controls and style them more easily.

I wand to do it without breaking Forms API and Ajax by changing form control type.

Comment: You can't just add class  to the button and in your CSS you add the :before :after icon ?

Comment: Indeed, you're right. But that's especially the problem : the submit buttons are inputs and not buttons by default in Forms API... I'm searching a way to change it without breaking Form API and eventually AJAX form features.